# Handling Google Maps InfoWindow Content with React

Tags: reactjs

I have markers on my google maps and each marker can be clicked and show some information about the marker. That info is a string html format which contains some links in it. I want to call a react function when a link is clicked. How can I do that? Now the function **_onClick(p)** get called soon on render, I've modified the calling method of the function but it doesn't work.

```
_onClick(p){
    alert('HELLO ' + p.id)
},

_renderPoints(positions){
    const markers = []
    let center
    positions.forEach((p) => {
        if (p.latLng){
            const point = new google.maps.LatLng(p.latLng.lat,p.latLng.lng)
            const marker_title = p.code
            const marker_content = `<b>${p.customerName}</b><br/>
                                    <a href="#" onClick=${this._onClick(p)}>Click</a><br/>
                                    <a href="#" style="color:mediumblue" onClick="window.open('${p.customerPhoto}','Foto Rumah ','resizable,height=260,width=370');return false;">${p.customerAddress}</a><br/>
                                    <div style="margin-top:5px">
                                        stand kini: <a href="#" onClick="window.open('${p.currentStandPhoto}','Foto Meter Bulan Ini ','resizable,height=300,width=300');return false;">${p.currentStand}</a><br/>
                                        stand lalu: <a href="#" onClick="window.open('${p.previousStandPhoto}','Foto Meter Bulan Lalu ','resizable,height=300,width=300');return false;">${p.previousStand}</a>
                                    </div>`
            const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: this.state.map,
                    title: marker_title
                })

            const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: marker_content
            });

            marker.addListener('click',function () {
                infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
            })
            markers.push(marker)
            center = point
        }
    })
    this.setState({
        markers
    })
    if (center){
        this.state.map.setCenter(center)
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `onClick` function for anchor tag in your code has treated as string, instead, you should make your on component, try code beloow, and change
this code `const marker_content = ....` into `const marker_content = <InfoWindow data={p}/>`

```js
const InfoWindow = React.createClass({
 _onClick(p){
  console.log(p)
 },
 render: function() {
  var p = this.props.data
  return (<div>
    <b>${p.customerName}</b><br/>
      <a href="#" onClick=${() => {this._onClick()}}>Click</a><br/>
      <a href="#" style="color:mediumblue" onClick="window.open('${p.customerPhoto}','Foto Rumah ','resizable,height=260,width=370');return false;">${p.customerAddress}</a><br/>
      <div style="margin-top:5px">
           stand kini: <a href="#" onClick="window.open('${p.currentStandPhoto}','Foto Meter Bulan Ini ','resizable,height=300,width=300');return false;">${p.currentStand}</a><br/>
           stand lalu: <a href="#" onClick="window.open('${p.previousStandPhoto}','Foto Meter Bulan Lalu ','resizable,height=300,width=300');return false;">${p.previousStand}</a>
      </div>
  </div>)
 }
})
```

let me know if that's work, hope it's helpfull